# How do you query an int column for any value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select

How can you query a column for any value in that column? (ie. How do I build a dynamic where clause that can either filter the value, or not.)

I want to be able to query for either a specific value, or not. For instance, I might want the value to be 1, but I might want it to be any number.

Is there a way to use a wild card (like "*"), to match any value, so that it can be dynamically inserted where I want no filter?

For instance:

```
select int_col from table where int_col = 1  // Query for a specific value
select int_col from table where int_col = *  // Query for any value
```

The reason why I do not want to use 2 separate SQL statements is because I am using this as a SQL Data Source, which can only have 1 select statement.

Comment: A wildcard for what? You can do `WHERE col = 1`, `WHERE col > 2`, `WHERE col IN (3,4)`, etc. But wildcards are for strings. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Can you provide an example data set and result ? If you want to allow any value, just dont include it in a where clause.

Comment: You should have mentioned it was a stored procedure...

Comment: Ok sorry, didn't think it make too much difference.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> Sometimes I would query for actual value (like 1, 2...) so I can't not have a condition either.

I take it you want some dynamic behavior on your `WHERE` clause, without having to dynamically *build* your `WHERE` clause.

With a single parameter, you can use `ISNULL` (or `COALESCE`) like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = ISNULL(@id, ID)
```

which allows a `NULL` parameter to match all. Some prefer the longer but more explicit:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (@id IS NULL) OR (ID = @id)
```

Comment: Yep, got it to work, I'll accept the answer in 3 min after it becomes available.

Comment: Very neat solution.

Comment: Small improvement, because of I need to use the `0` value as `all`: 
`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = ISNULL( NULLIF(@id, 0), ID)`

Answer (score 7):

A simple answer would be use: IS NOT NULL.  But if you are asking for say 123* for numbers like 123456 or 1234 or 1237 then the you could convert it to a varchar and then test against using standard wild cards.

In your where clause: `cast(myIntColumn as varchar(15)) like '123%'`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the value you're filtering on is a parameter in a stored procedure, or contained in a variable called `@Value`, you can do it like this:

```
select * from table where @Value is null or intCol = @Value
```

If `@Value` is null then the `or` part of the clause is ignored, so the query won't filter on intCol.

Comment: Yep, same as with Mark's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parameter as a wildcard by assigning special meaning to NULL:

```
DECLARE @q INT = 1
SELECT * FROM table WHERE IntegerColumn = @q OR @q IS NULL
```

This way, when you pass in NULL; you get all rows.

If NULL is a valid value to query for, then you need to use two parameters.

Comment: But what about when I need to query for specific value?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. The easiest thing is really to omit the predicate part, as others mention - but I updated my answer with a possible solution for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of wildcards for numbers are the comparators.

So, if you wanted to find all positive integers:

```
select int_col from table where int_col > 0
```

any numbers between a hundred and a thousand:

```
select int_col from table where int_col BETWEEN 100 AND 1000
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you're asking. I think you should use two different queries for the different situations you have.

**When you're not looking for a specific value:**

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

**When you are looking for a specific value:**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE intcol = 1
```

Comment: SQL Data Source only have 1 select statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the value of your column for all rows on the table you can simply use

```
select int_col
  from table
```

If you want to know all the distinct values, but don't care how many times they're repeated you can use

```
select distinct int_col
  from table
```

And if you want to know all the distinct values and how many times they each appear, use

```
select int_col, count(*)
  from table
  group by int_col
```

To have the values sorted properly you can add

```
  order by int_col
```

to all the queries above.

Share and enjoy.