# Django filter for ANY value in a MySql column

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to be able to use this filter for "specific" or "null" or "**any value**" scenarios

```
#  3 scenarios for the third field : Col3 

#  Query for a specific value
sample = table.objects.filter(Col1=343, Col2=545, Col3=656)

#  Query for NULL value
sample = table.objects.filter(Col1=343, Col2=545, Col3=None)

#  Query for any value
sample = table.objects.filter(Col1=343, Col2=545, Col3=???)
```

Specific and NULL scenarios are handled by exact values like 656 and "None" in python.
**How do we handle ANY value scnearios from above ?**

Imagine 3 drop down boxes based on which we can query the database.

My question is similar to this one, but specific to Django

original sql specific question is here: [How do you query an int column for any value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622260/how-do-you-query-an-int-column-for-any-value) , coloumn in my case can be of any type

resulting query might look something like this:

```
// Query for a specific value
select Col1,Col2,Col3 from table where Col1=343, Col2=545, Col3=656       
// Query for NULL value
select Col1,Col2,Col3 from table where Col1=343, Col2=545, Col3 IS NULL
// Query for any value
select Col1,Col2,Col3 from table where Col1=343, Col2=545, Col3=*
```

Comment: have you tried `Col3__in=[656, None]`?

Comment: Have I misunderstood? so you want to either filter Col3=656, None or All dynaimcally?

Comment: yes the second comment is what i am looking for, and it can be any value not just 656...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774133/django-conditional-filter-based-on-local-variable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651211/django-conditionally-filtering-objects

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following statement:

```py
# Query for any value
sample = table.objects.filter(Col1=343, Col2=545, Col3__regex = r'.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to omit the `Col3` filter like this:

```
sample = table.objects.filter(Col1=343, Col2=545)
```

Edit: Are you trying to condense all of these cases into a single statement?

I'm not familiar enough with the subtleties of QuerySets in Django to give you a one-liner, but, taking your 3 dropdown boxes example a bit further...what if your dropdowns contained 'None' and 'Any' in addition to the regular list of values? That way you could select a query based on the parameters provided.

```
if param3 == 'None':
    sample = table.objects.filter(Col1=343, Col2=545, Col3=None)
elif param3 == 'Any':
    sample = table.objects.filter(Col1=343, Col2=545)
else:
    sample = table.objects.filter(Col1=343, Col2=545, Col3=param3)
```

Comment: @user1035818: I've edited my answer - it should do the trick until someone with a bit more experience with Django can help you.

Comment: I have already done it this way, but there has to be some better way to condense it. I have 5 columns on which I want to apply these cases, so condensing it makes it really tidy, rather than going for a big if-else block. Appreciate your help. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774133/django-conditional-filter-based-on-local-variable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651211/django-conditionally-filtering-objects