# Django conditional filter based on local variable

Tags: python, django, filter

I'm new with django and was wondering if there is a more efficient way to filter conditionally besides if statement.

Given:

```
test_names = ["all"]
test_types = ["a", "b", "c"]
... (more lists)
```

I know I can do this:

```
q = tests.objects.all()

if test_names[0] == "all":
    q = q.all()
else:
    q = q.filter("name__in=test_names")

if test_types[0] == "all":
    q = q.all()
else:
    q = q.filter("type__in=test_type")

etc...
```

I would like something like this:

```
q = test.objects \
        .filter((if test_names[0]=="all") "name__in=test_names") \
        .filter((if test_types[0]=="all") "type__in=test_types") \
        ...etc
```

I want to avoid the if statement because I have to do this several times on the same query data based on different lists like "test_names".

Answer (score 2):

You have conditions in your list, so you need `if`s for different conditions for sure. You might be able to get away with one query statement but you need to work on your lists:

```
test_name_filter = {} if test_names[0] == 'all' else {'name__in': test_names}
test_type_filter = {} if test_type[0] == 'all' else {'type__in': test_types}
# ......
q = test.objects.filter(**test_name_filter).filter(**test_type_filter)
```

This should work because:

1. Django ORM filter can accept filter conditions as a dict, keys as criteria and values as filter values.
2. Empty dict is like not filtering on anything, means returns everything.